# Callback URL param for facebook client-side app

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, callback, scribe

I'm using facebook4j api (http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html) for access to user data on facebook, so for the login authorization i must provide a acess token, so i found this api: (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) and from this example (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java) i'm trying to get the access token, in the params builder i have to set the callback url:

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
    .provider(FacebookApi.class)
    .apiKey(Assets.FACEBOOK_APPID)
    .apiSecret(Assets.FACEBOOK_APPSECRET)
    .callback()
    .build();
```

But my app is client-side only, so what callback url must i provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/):

> redirect_uri. The URL that you want to redirect the person logging in back to. This URL will capture the response from the Login Dialog. If you are using this in a webview within a desktop app, this must be set to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

Comment: I've seen that, but not helped me much, because i still don't know how to make a login form

Comment: In your question, you are asking about a callback URL which is given above. If that is not what you want, redefine your question.

Comment: Yeah, i´m asking for a callback URL, i don't know what param i need to provide, https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html don't work, i want to know where i can find it

Comment: an more detailed description is that when my app calls the url i get this message in the broswer: Success

SECURITY WARNING : Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

Comment: The URL of the loaded page should contain your access token as a parameter, just parse it from there. I just did something like this some days ago, but don't have the code with me now. [edit] Just to clarify, this is a **redirect** URL. If this is unclear to you, read about the authentication flow on the Facebook developer documentation.